# Issue with Tomcat Integration to AEM

Tags: tomcat, aem

can you guide me Integrate Tomcat server to AEM.

1) Installed Tomcat 8.5, conf directory on that port changed to 4502

2) Open     /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.33/crx-quickstart/bin/catalina.sh and add enough memory
 set JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1792m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

3) Rename cq-quickstart-5.6.0-20130125.war to ROOT.war

4) Extract the file web.xml in ROOT.war (ROOT.war\WEB-INF\web.xml) onto the filesystem.
Open extracted web.xml in a text editor and change init-param sling.home from crx-quickstart to /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.33/crx-quickstart

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>sling.home</param-name>
     <param-value>/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.33/crx-quickstart</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

5) Copy ROOT.war to /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.33/webappsOpen cmd prompt at /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.33/bin and start server using the command 
$ sudo ./catalina.sh run

6)Check the folder /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.33/crx-quickstart and the following folders should have be created

```
         launchpad
         logs
         repository
```

Here I got launchpad and logs directories created under crx-quickstart directory.

7) Open a browser window and type http://localhost:4502 redirect to http://localhost:8080/system/granite/license/index.html for license information. If you have license.properties get the customer name and license key from file, and enter in the form.

8) I am opening on browser localhost:4502 getting 503 Error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/application-server-install.html#Tomcat885

Comment: Is this a clean install? What is the AEM version?